# Repeating a for loop until completion?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, repeat

I need to create a function that will remove the even numbers in any lists tested by my program, however, it stops after removing the first even number and I'm not sure how to keep it going

```
def filter_odds(data):
     for index in range(len(data)):
        index = data[index]
        if index % 2 == 0:
            data.remove(index)
        else:
            continue
        return data
print(filter_odds([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

Comment: is the indentation for that `return` correct, where you have it?

Comment: it is, I've tried to adjust where the return is to no avail

Comment: @zahnzy: He means it's looks like that your `return` is inside the for loop.

Comment: @KevinGuan turns out that it was, thanks!

Comment: Don't reuse variables like `index = data[index]`. It makes it harder to understand your program.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

1. `return` is inside the loop body, so it returns after looping once
2. You're mutating the `list` during iteration, and you'll die with an `IndexError` because the loop runs to the original length of the `list`, even though the `list` shrinks as you go.

Either way, `list` comprehensions would do this more nicely:

```
def filter_odds(data):
    return [x for x in data if x % 2]
```

If for some reason you need to mutate the argument, not just return a modified copy of the values you care about, you can do that easily too:

```
def filter_odds(data):
    # Assigning to slice with no end points replaces contents with values
    # from new list, modifying in place
    data[:] = [x for x in data if x % 2]
    return data     # Return the mutated argument as in original code
```

If the goal is to remove even indices instead of even values, you'd use extended slicing to do this crazy efficiently and Pythonically:

```
def filter_odds(data):
    return data[1::2]
```

Or mutating the argument:

```
def filter_odds(data):
    del data[::2]   # Deletes the even indices in place in a single pass
    return data     # Return the mutated argument as in original code
```

Comment: This will return numbers at even indexes, not necessarily even numbers.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Ah, missed the horrible misuse of `index` in the original code (being both the index, and later reassigned to the value at said index). I've included both solutions, depending on which approach was actually intended.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
odd_list = [num for num in data if num % 2 == 1]
```

Comment: he said `will remove the even numbers`, he wants an array of the odd numbers, I think you need to change `==` to `!=`

Comment: Thanks, got it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
def filter_odds(data):
    list = []
    for index in data:
        if index % 2 != 0:
            list.append(index)
        else:
            pass
    return list

print(filter_odds([1,2,3,4,5,6])) # returns [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: the `else` is unneccessary

Comment: 1. Don't use `list` as a variable name, use `l` instead. 2. Also `return [index for index in data if index % 2 != 0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did exactly what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the else statement and the return wasn't  indented properly

```
    def filter_odds(data):
     for number in data:           
       if number % 2 == 0:
         data.remove(number)
      # else:
      #   continue
     return data
    print(filter_odds([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I just tried this with a few other sets, and for some reason it still did not remove them all. For example, I used the set filter_odds([95, 58, 9, 22, 42, 11, 57],). This needed to return only  [95, 9, 11, 57], but it returned [95, 9, 42, 11, 57].                edit: the solution by J4mie seemed to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `filter` function:

```
even_list = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, input_list)
odd_list = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, input_list)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter